# Is there a default web user group on CentOS Linux?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, centos

I am used to Ubuntu and now have CentOS.  For my other web servers (on ubuntu) there is a user and/or group call "www-data" Is this something specific to Ubuntu or the LAMP appliance that I installed?

On my CentOS account it looks like the owner is 6226? How does this relate to www-data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Centos:

- Apache Webserver, it runs as forks off to the apache user, apache group
- MySQL runs as a mysql user, mysql group

Comment: Are you saying that 6226 is Apache User or the Apache group?

Comment: Default apache id for user is 48
Default apache id for group is 48

ID 6226, not sure what this. How did you determine that ID?  that could the the PID that the apache service was running at

Comment: OK, well I found that by checking the permissions via WinSCP.

Comment: OK, so 6226 is NOT a user group.

Comment: OK, so 6226 is listed as the owner of the files in the HTML folder.  I'm a bit clueless. Doing research.  Consulting my pocket linux book for guidance.

Comment: I had some luck changing permissions to apache when I needed to.

Answer (score -1):

Same issue here, on a development server.

```
# ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    4096 2011-01-23 00:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root    4096 2011-02-03 10:11 ..
drwxr-xr-x 9 6226 6226    4096 2010-12-15 14:17 d
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root    4096 2011-01-23 13:51 htdocs
```

"d" is a drupal installation, and the directory was created with:

```
# tar -xzvf drupal.tar.gz
```

Using tar to directly examine its archive:

```
# gunzip drupal.tar.gz
# tar -tvf drupal.tar

-rw-r--r-- bender/bender    765 2007-09-10 13:29 drupal-6.20/themes/pushbutton/forum-link-rtl.png
```

Only one line is included because they *all* show the same owner/group. A quick Google search shows a few similar cases. Mystery solved?

Comment: You have 6226 because whoever packages the Drupal tarballs does so when logged in with a user whose uid and gid are 6226 on their system.